# Printing iframes with src set to another domain workaround with javascript

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, printing

We already know that you cannot print iframe content coming in from another domain. I was trying to work around this by opening the iframe in a new window and printing it through there:

```
<body>
   Other markup on the page that we don't want print here...
   <input type="button" value="Open window" onclick="openWin()" />
   <iframe name="iframeID" src="http://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/1490630/000110465914022639/a14-8878_1ex10d1.htm" frameborder="0" style="overflow:hidden;height:100%;width:100%"></iframe>

   Other stuff that shouldn't print here...
</body>
```

javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function openWin()
  {
    var popWindow=window.open('http://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/1490630/000110465914022639/a14-8878_1ex10d1.htm','','width=600,height=700');

    popWindow.document.close();
    popWindow.focus();
    popWindow.print();
    popWindow.close();

  }
</script>
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BD3wQ/)

what that does it opens the window and closes it right away, looks like popWindow.print() doesn't do anything.

If we remove the url then it works, but the content is blank of course:

```
var popWindow=window.open('','','width=600,height=700');
```

any way to get the content from the url to load in the popup and print it?

Comment: Have you tried it without the `popWindow.close()`?  Possibly `popWindow.print()` is asynchronous, so that call returns immediately and the `close()` happens straight away.

Comment: i have. if print() gets called, it waits for the user to respond before triggering close(). so print() isn't getting called.